# Students who received Smicha from Rabbi Akiva Eger

Tags: history, rabbis, semicha

I'm seeking a list of Rabbis who received Smicha from R. Akiva Eger, both in Markisch Friedland and later in Posen.

Comment: Why do you want to know this? Is this JeLLy enough?

Comment: @DoubleAA, it's a question of history of Judaism, not just of Jews, so is on-topic IMO. Jim Bennett, by "JeLLy", DoubleAA meant (roughly) "on-topic": see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I hope you stick around and post good questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if they received *semicha* per say from Rabbi Akiva Eiger, but Rabbi Eliyahu Gutmacher, Rabbi Zvi Hirsch Kallischer, and Rabbi Shlomo Eiger are known to be his foremost students.